# Setblock replace door without particle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everytime i setblock replace a door to air , it always emit the "break" particle for the other half of the door , how do i disable that ? because it ruin the mood.

Do not use mod please , only for pure vanilla .

Comment: What command are you using, exactly?

Comment: @SF just a simple command , for example my coordinate is in a block with a door block , then i just /setblock ~ ~ ~ air , the door does get removed but it emit a break particle when it disappear , which totally ruin the mood of my map if i do it many time automatically using command block , if i do it many time it will continuously emit particle which i dont know how to remove , thats why i ask this question , i remember this is not a thing in 1.8 but in 1.16.3 setblock replace emit the particle

Comment: Have you tried using the fill command?  Does this happen to every block or just doors?

Comment: @randomuser922 THANK YOUU !!!! you can submit in on answer section and i will mark it as accepted answer , THANKS SOO MUCH

Comment: sorry i just figured out that it only happen to door block and not other block , so i edited my question

Comment: I updated my answer and it should now make it work like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that the `setblock` command emits particles when replacing a door.  The `fill` command can also replace blocks.  The `fill` command doubly can replace whole doors and other blocks that uses multiple tiles as particles should emit from this blocks.  What you are doing is replacing the base of the door with air, then in the next tick the game finds that the base is gone so it removes the top, by adding particles and sounds.

## How to use the fill command instead

Your command should be the following.

```
/fill <start cords> <finish cords> <block>
```

If you want to fill one block just use the same cords for the start and stop.  To replace doors make sure to have the start cords at the base and the stop at the top of the door.